Problem with Omniscript's Custom Lightning Stylesheet File
I inserted a Custom Lightning Stylesheet File into my Omniscript, but it is working not only on it, but on all page record the component is on.
How to fix this?
The  Custom Lightning Stylesheet File :
.slds-accordion__summary-action {
    background: rgb(243, 243, 243);
}

.omni-read-only [data-omni-input] .slds-radio_faux, .omni-read-only [data-omni-input] input:not([type=range]):not([type=checkbox]):not([type=radio]), .omni-read-only [data-omni-input] input[type=url], .omni-read-only [data-omni-input] select, .omni-read-only [data-omni-input] textarea {
    border-color: transparent !important ;
    color: black;
    caret-color: transparent;
    background: transparent;
    border-bottom: var(--lwc-borderWidthThin,1px) solid var(--slds-g-color-border-base-1, var(--lwc-colorBorder,rgb(229, 229, 229))) !important;

}

input{
    border: transparent !important;
    border-bottom: var(--lwc-borderWidthThin,1px) solid var(--slds-g-color-border-base-1, var(--lwc-colorBorder,rgb(229, 229, 229))) !important;

}

.omni-block_content[vlocity_ins-omniscriptBlock_omniscriptBlock] {
    padding-left: 0rem !important; 
}


I solved it adding flexipage-component2[data-component-id="c_myOmniscriptName"] before each tag
flexipage-component2[data-component-id="c_myOmniscriptName"] .slds-accordion__summary-action {
    background: rgb(243, 243, 243);
}

flexipage-component2[data-component-id="c_myOmniscriptName"] .omni-read-only [data-omni-input] .slds-radio_faux,
flexipage-component2[data-component-id="c_myOmniscriptName"] .omni-read-only [data-omni-input] input:not([type=range]):not([type=checkbox]):not([type=radio]),
flexipage-component2[data-component-id="c_myOmniscriptName"] .omni-read-only [data-omni-input] input[type=url],
flexipage-component2[data-component-id="c_myOmniscriptName"] .omni-read-only [data-omni-input] select,
flexipage-component2[data-component-id="c_myOmniscriptName"] .omni-read-only [data-omni-input] textarea {
    border-color: transparent !important;
    color: black;
    caret-color: transparent;
    background: transparent;
    border-bottom: var(--lwc-borderWidthThin, 1px) solid var(--slds-g-color-border-base-1, var(--lwc-colorBorder, rgb(229, 229, 229))) !important;
}

flexipage-component2[data-component-id="c_myOmniscriptName"] input {
    border: transparent !important;
    border-bottom: var(--lwc-borderWidthThin, 1px) solid var(--slds-g-color-border-base-1, var(--lwc-colorBorder, rgb(229, 229, 229))) !important;
}

flexipage-component2[data-component-id="c_myOmniscriptName"] .omni-block_content[vlocity_ins-omniscriptBlock_omniscriptBlock] {
    padding-left: 0rem !important;
}

